# What is the Time Complexity of this java recursive function?

Tags: java, recursion, time-complexity

```
class Solution {
    public static int countBinarySubstrings(String s) {
        int res = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < s.length()-1; i++) {

            if(s.charAt(i) != s.charAt(i+1)) 
                res += countValid(s, i, i+1);
        }
        return res;
    }
    
    public static int countValid(String s, int start, int end) {
        //base case
        if(start < 0 || end >= s.length()) 
            return 0;
        if(end-start == 1)
            return countValid(s, start-1, end+1) + 1;
        if(s.charAt(start+1) == s.charAt(start) && s.charAt(end-1) == s.charAt(end))
            return countValid(s, start-1, end+1) + 1;
        else
            return 0;
    }
    
}
```

Leetcode problem https://leetcode.com/problems/count-binary-substrings/

The solution works but I have a hard time coming up with time complexity for recursive solutions.

Anytime the loop encounters s.charAt(i) != s.charAt(i+1), it makes recursive calls to expand until it reaches base case or the else part.

Since I'm traversing the entire string, the for loop is O(n). But how to determine the number of recursive calls that will be made since it will depend on the if condition.

As for the space complexity, the worst case occurs when s = "00...000011111...11". In this case, 01 occurs right in the middle so the recursive calls will keep on expanding until the start and end index are out of bounds. By then, the code will have made n/2 calls so the space complexity is O(N).

I'm stuck on the time complexity.

Answer (score 0):

First, consider any given top-level call of `isValid()`.

We can see the pattern by which it calls itself. It starts somewhere in what can be assumed to be the middle of the string, and expands the borders continuously until either they're out of range, or the numbers no longer match. *In the worst case* (starting in the middle and extending out all the way to the end, this results in calling the method `n/2` times, which is the time complexity class `O(n)`.

Now, we can consider `countBinarySubstrings()`, which calls `isValid()` `n` times. `O(n * n) = O(n^2)`.

In terms of space complexity, only a single integer is allocated in `countBinarySubstrings()`, and no space is allocated inside `countValid()`. We usually don't count the stack space taken up by the method calls themselves in a method's space complexity, and we don't count the space taken up by the input itself either, so we could say this has `O(1)` space complextiy (or `O(n)` if you want to count the stack space from recursive calls).

Keep in mind that O-notation records the worst-case complexity of a procedure. Ω-notation records the best-case and Θ-notation records the average-case complexity, which is usually a bit harder to calculate but we usually don't care much about it.

Comment: Doesn't O(n * n) means we are calling countValid() n times for each iteration in for loop n. But here, you said the worst case is 000...000111...111 where the countValid() will be called in the middle. Once the countValid() is called in the loop, it will be called n times  (only once) and that's it right? The loop would just continue to iterate without calling countValid() again because if statement will equate to false. So how's it O(n * n)?

Comment: @CrazyCSGuy computational complexity is a general measure of _how runtime increases relative to the size of the input_. A single top-level call of `countValid()` has time complexity `O(n)`, and `countBinarySubstrings()` can execute a top-level call of that method up to `n` times. If you can prove that the number of `countValid()` calls total is linear with respect to the input (this does seem to be the case, you're right), then the entire thing would be `O(n)`, but from a high level it looks like `O(n^2)`.